# How to show count of any jstree in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using google tag manager to fire tags for my website, I created custom javascript variable which returns count of my jstree selection (i.e how many users selected how many items) and i placed a trigger on this count, just wanna know if there is any way that i can see this count on my google analytics page so as to analyse how many users are selecting how many items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found answer myself, Hope it will help others too.

To show count of any custom variable that you created on your google tag manager  on your Google Analytics page is possible by creating custom dimensions on Google Analytics. Steps for doing this are below :-

- Go to your google Analytics account, open admin section.
  -Then go under property-->custom definations and select custom dimensions
- click on new custom dimension add name and select scope "session" and click on create (Note :- please note your dimension index).
- Go to google tag manager, Create a new tag, click on more settings under "configure tag" and add custom dimension, place index number and dimension value(custom variable that you created) here.
- set your firing rule and save it.

Now, you can see it under report by setting secondary dimensions as custom dimensions. Also if you want to further analysis on this data you can also use Biq Query plugin for GA.

You are ready to go!!

Comment: Please mark this as answer as well, by clicking on the tick mark!